# Set up naked (root domain) url AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I am having trouble to set up a root domain url for my website which is hosted on amazon ELB.

The Route53 configuration is:

```
example.io. NS ns-540.awsdns-03.net. 
example.io. NS ns-457.awsdns-57.com. 
example.io. NS ns-1619.awsdns-10.co.uk. 
example.io. NS ns-1209.awsdns-23.org.
example.io. SOA ns-540.awsdns-03.net.awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 
www.example.io. A ALIAS dualstack.awseb-e-i-awsebloa-hn2w7ngc0kov-996406187.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com. (z1h1fl5habsf5)
```

I am able to access my app with www.example.io, but not with http://example.io. What I am missing in my configuration to make it work with the root domain url?

I would slightly prefer that the www.example.io redirects to the root domain url. That would allow users to use the app at http://example.io which I think is better. However, if this is complicated I am fine with the root domain url redirecting to the www.example.io.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an A record for the root domain in your zone for the elastic beanstalk app, try adding the following (with your correct target)

```
example.io. A ALIAS dualstack.awseb-e-etcetc
```

Comment: I've already tried but it seems that amazon deosn't let you do that, at least from the gui.

Comment: I've just done the same for another domain I have in R53 and it works. Leave 'Name' blank, 'Type' as 'A - IPv4 address', 'Alias' as 'Yes', 'Alias target' let it resolve all your EB environments and then click on the correct one.